# InstallShield XML File Merge

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

I am using a config XML file with my installer and I need when user upgrades my installer, the new config file generated should be merged with previous config file, 
so it should save the changes user have made on previous config files + it should also show the new config file changes and all well merged.

I used InstallShield XML file changes option, but when I changed some content in installed Config File and upgraded the software, it instead of merging the content, added a duplicate node to new xml file.

Below is what is happening : 
Original XML File :

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
   <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup>
    </configuration>
```

User manually altered useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="false" and after when user upgraded the software, the xml becomes

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
         <configuration>
       <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="false">
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0">               </supportedRuntime>
</startup>
 <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"></supportedRuntime>
</startup>
</configuration>
```

so basically, it is duplicating the node instead of merging it, Is there any way with installShield, we can handle XML config file Merges.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

When you use InstallShield XML Changes - you can modify an element if it exists, but do not create it if it does not exist.
 
Please refer to [XPath Expressions](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield18helplib/XML-XPath.htm) documentation do it, I suppose, Example 3, there is for you.

Comment: I need to save config data which user has changed in configuration so if I make any change in config file and upgrade the software, it duplicates the specific node .

Comment: Then you need create specific key for tag and search element by this key. For example, add to xml tag  <startup> one more key:  `<startup id="1" useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">...` then you could find this element by key **id** and modify what you need.